# Django template within a for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
<ul>
{% for post in latest_post_list %}
    <li>{{ post }}</li>
</ul>

{% empty %}
<p>No posts are available.</p>

{% endfor %}
```

But I want to wrap each post object in a template, so for example:

```
{% for post in latest_post_list %}
    {% include 'jobposttemplate.html' %}


{% empty %}
{% include 'noposts.html' %}

{% endfor %}
```

jobposttemplate.html will then include all the various information held within the JobPost model.

I tried:

```
{% for jobposttemplate.html in latest_post_list %}
    {{ jobposttemplate.html }}


{% empty %}
{% include 'noposts.html' %}

{% endfor %}
```

But, predictably, it didn't work. Basically I'm just trying to avoid having to  having to write the html out each time, e.g.:

```
{% for post in latest_post_list %}
<div style="blah">{{ post.deadline }}
</div>  
    <div style="schmah">{{ post.created_at }}
</div>  

{% empty %}
<p>No posts are available.</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You forgotten the quotes?    {% include 'jobposttemplate.html' %}

Comment: Just a typo..sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using app specific subfolders inside your `templates/` directory, you need to add them to the file name here too.

```
{% include 'myapp/jobposttemplate.html' %}
```

And if you want the template to have access to variables, you can add them to the template's scope using `with`. The sub-template also has access to all scope variables too.

```
{% include 'myapp/jobposttemplate.html' with object=post %}
```

Comment: So if my model is called JobPost, I would have `{% for job in latest_post_list %} {% include 'jobpost.html' with JobPost=post %}` ? I have 4 JobPost objects, so running this code creates 4 templates. Should each of these then correspond to one specific object? I've tried calling object attributes to test but nothing I try displays any object information.

Comment: To clarify, the correct code I was looking for was `{% for job in latest_post_list %} {% include 'jobpost.html' with job=job %}` This adds `job` variable to the context for use in jobpost.html.